# I've used xmlslurper to define the xml result from a JDBC query but how do I assert on pieces of the result?

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui, assert

I've got a string of xml as the response from this script,
//
import groovy.json.*

def resp = new XmlSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.getResponse().responseContent)

assert (resp == "whateverwhatever"), "ERROR:  invalid result!!"

return
//

and I want to assert on pieces of the long concatenated string that the resp object is.
I just queried and am getting back a record(s) from a database with 5 columns (those 5 cols of text are the "whateverwhatever" example text)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add some sample data to your question please ? It's a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly apply assert on that XML object you get

you can use like below the getAt and similar function to get the whole or some specific content from XML and then apply the assert

```
def content = context.expand('${Request#Request}')
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(content)
def token = xml.getAt("Token")
log.info token
```

Try using log.info to know the details at each step

Sharing some sample code which can guide you to achieve assertion on XML

```
def parsedResponse = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
String convertedValue = parsedResponse.Body.ConversionRateResponse.
ConversionRateResult.text()
log.info(convertedValue)
```

Here from the XML we are trying to reach a particular node with dot operator and then the text we get we are asserting it